# Pull down menu from Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, uinavigationbar, custom-controls

Does anyone know of a good solution to attaching a retractable menu to the bottom of the navigation bar?

I have found this: https://github.com/mentionapp/mntpulltoreact, but this has the behavior of pulling down on the whole view, not letting go, and then selecting the item that one wants by dragging your finger along.

The Zappos app has a perfect example of what I am looking for. Does anyone know what they could have been using or an existing solution for this? I've searched on cocoacontrols and haven't found much. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would doing something like this work for you?  then of course you can just add whatever menu buttons you need to the menu view.

```
UIView * menu;
UIButton * activate;
int menuHeight;
int buttonHeight;

-(void)toggleMenu:(UIButton*)sender{

    [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:menu];

    if (sender.tag == 1000){

        [UIView transitionWithView:menu duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(menu.frame.origin.x,menu.frame.origin.y - menu.frame.size.height + buttonHeight ,menu.frame.size.width,menu.frame.size.height);

            menu.frame = frame;

            [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        } completion:nil];

        sender.tag = 2000;

    } else {

        [UIView transitionWithView:menu duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(menu.frame.origin.x,menu.frame.origin.y + menu.frame.size.height - buttonHeight  ,menu.frame.size.width,menu.frame.size.height);

            menu.frame = frame;

            [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        } completion:nil];

        sender.tag = 1000;
    }

}



menuHeight = 100;
buttonHeight = 20;

activate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[activate addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[activate setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
activate.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, menuHeight - buttonHeight, 70.0, buttonHeight);
activate.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

activate.tag = 2000;

menu = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 - menuHeight + buttonHeight,self.view.bounds.size.width, menuHeight)];

menu.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

menu.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

[self.view addSubview:menu];
[menu addSubview:activate];
```

Comment: This should definitely work! I'll have to figure out how to make it push down my tableView header, but that shouldn't take too long

Answer (score 1):

you can then use some constraints to shift the table down and what not.  this is untested but should get you pointed in the right direction

```
-(void)toggleMenu:(UIButton*)sender{


    UIView * menu;

    [sender setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:menu];

    id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;

    NSDictionary * viewsDictionary;

    viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myTable, topGuide, bottomGuide, menu);

    NSArray * newVertConstraint;


    if (sender.tag == 1000){

        newVertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[bottomGuide][menu(==%f)][myTable][bottomGuide]|", 0.0] options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

        sender.tag = 2000;

    } else {
        newVertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[bottomGuide][menu(==%f)][myTable][bottomGuide]|", menu.frame.size.height] options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];        
        sender.tag = 1000;
    }

    [self.view removeConstraints:vertConstraint];

    [self.view addConstraints:newVertConstraint];
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    vertConstraint = newVertConstraint;

}




NSArray * vertConstraint;

UITableView * myTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:myTable];


self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
[myTable setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
[menu setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary;

viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myTable, topGuide, bottomGuide, menu);

vertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[bottomGuide][menu(==0)][myTable][bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:vertConstraint];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[menu]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myTable]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make this view stick to the bottom of the navigation bar when pulling down? instead of it coming down with the whole scroll view?